# ArrayList in android returns unwanted results

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I've created the Earthquake class to define an object consist of three strings as shown here:

```
    package com.example.android.quake;

    public class Earthquake {

    // @param magnitude earth quake magnitude
    private String mMagnitude;

    // @param city location of earthquake
    private String mLocation;

    // @param date , the  date of the earthquake
    private String mDate;

    public Earthquake(String mag, String loc, String date) {
        this.mMagnitude = mag;
        this.mLocation = loc;
        this.mDate = date;
    }

    public void setMagnitude(String magnitude) {
        this.mMagnitude = magnitude;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.mLocation = location;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.mDate = date;
    }

    public String getMagnitude() {
        return mMagnitude;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return mLocation;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return mDate;
    }
   }
```

Then when I try to create an ArrayList of Earthquake object type as shown here:

```
    package com.example.android.quake;

    import android.util.Log;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * Helper methods related to requesting and receiving earthquake data from USGS.
     */
    public final class QueryUtils {

        /** Sample JSON response for a USGS query */
        private static final String SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE = "{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\",\"metadata\":{\"generated\":1462295443000,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-01-01&endtime=2016-01-31&minmag=6&limit=10\",\"title\":\"USGS Earthquakes\",\"status\":200,\"api\":\"1.5.2\",\"limit\":10,\"offset\":1,\"count\":10},\"features\":[{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":7.2,\"place\":\"88km N of Yelizovo, Russia\",\"time\":1454124312220,\"updated\":1460674294040,\"tz\":720,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us20004vvx\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us20004vvx&format=geojson\",\"felt\":2,\"cdi\":3.4,\"mmi\":5.82,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":798,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"20004vvx\",\"ids\":\",at00o1qxho,pt16030050,us20004vvx,gcmt20160130032510,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,finite-fault,general-link,general-text,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.958,\"rms\":1.19,\"gap\":17,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 7.2 - 88km N of Yelizovo, Russia\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[158.5463,53.9776,177]},\"id\":\"us20004vvx\"},\n" +
                "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.1,\"place\":\"94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea\",\"time\":1453777820750,\"updated\":1460156775040,\"tz\":600,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us20004uks\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us20004uks&format=geojson\",\"felt\":null,\"cdi\":null,\"mmi\":4.1,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":572,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"20004uks\",\"ids\":\",us20004uks,gcmt20160126031023,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,geoserve,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":1.537,\"rms\":0.74,\"gap\":25,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.1 - 94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[153.2454,-5.2952,26]},\"id\":\"us20004uks\"},\n" +
                "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.3,\"place\":\"50km NNE of Al Hoceima, Morocco\",\"time\":1453695722730,\"updated\":1460156773040,\"tz\":0,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004gy9\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004gy9&format=geojson\",\"felt\":117,\"cdi\":7.2,\"mmi\":5.28,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":695,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004gy9\",\"ids\":\",us10004gy9,gcmt20160125042203,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":2.201,\"rms\":0.92,\"gap\":20,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.3 - 50km NNE of Al Hoceima, Morocco\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-3.6818,35.6493,12]},\"id\":\"us10004gy9\"},\n" +
                "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":7.1,\"place\":\"86km E of Old Iliamna, Alaska\",\"time\":1453631430230,\"updated\":1460156770040,\"tz\":-540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004gqp\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004gqp&format=geojson\",\"felt\":1816,\"cdi\":7.2,\"mmi\":6.6,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":1496,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004gqp\",\"ids\":\",at00o1gd6r,us10004gqp,ak12496371,gcmt20160124103030,\",\"sources\":\",at,us,ak,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,finite-fault,general-link,general-text,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,trump-origin,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.72,\"rms\":2.11,\"gap\":19,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 7.1 - 86km E of Old Iliamna, Alaska\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-153.4051,59.6363,129]},\"id\":\"us10004gqp\"},\n" +
                "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.6,\"place\":\"215km SW of Tomatlan, Mexico\",\"time\":1453399617650,\"updated\":1459963829040,\"tz\":-420,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004g4l\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004g4l&format=geojson\",\"felt\":11,\"cdi\":2.7,\"mmi\":3.92,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":673,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004g4l\",\"ids\":\",at00o1bebo,pt16021050,us10004g4l,gcmt20160121180659,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":2.413,\"rms\":0.98,\"gap\":74,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.6 - 215km SW of Tomatlan, Mexico\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-106.9337,18.8239,10]},\"id\":\"us10004g4l\"},\n" +
                "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.7,\"place\":\"52km SE of Shizunai, Japan\",\"time\":1452741933640,\"updated\":1459304879040,\"tz\":540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004ebx\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004ebx&format=geojson\",\"felt\":51,\"cdi\":5.8,\"mmi\":6.45,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":720,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004ebx\",\"ids\":\",us10004ebx,pt16014050,at00o0xauk,gcmt20160114032534,\",\"sources\":\",us,pt,at,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",associate,cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.281,\"rms\":0.98,\"gap\":22,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.7 - 52km SE of Shizunai, Japan\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[142.781,41.9723,46]},\"id\":\"us10004ebx\"},\n" +
                "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.1,\"place\":\"12km WNW of Charagua, Bolivia\",\"time\":1452741928270,\"updated\":1459304879040,\"tz\":-240,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004ebw\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004ebw&format=geojson\",\"felt\":3,\"cdi\":2.2,\"mmi\":2.21,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":573,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004ebw\",\"ids\":\",us10004ebw,gcmt20160114032528,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":5.492,\"rms\":1.04,\"gap\":16,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.1 - 12km WNW of Charagua, Bolivia\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-63.3288,-19.7597,582.56]},\"id\":\"us10004ebw\"},\n" +
                "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.2,\"place\":\"74km NW of Rumoi, Japan\",\"time\":1452532083920,\"updated\":1459304875040,\"tz\":540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004djn\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004djn&format=geojson\",\"felt\":8,\"cdi\":3.4,\"mmi\":3.74,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":594,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004djn\",\"ids\":\",us10004djn,gcmt20160111170803,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":1.139,\"rms\":0.96,\"gap\":33,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.2 - 74km NW of Rumoi, Japan\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[141.0867,44.4761,238.81]},\"id\":\"us10004djn\"},\n" +
                "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.5,\"place\":\"227km SE of Sarangani, Philippines\",\"time\":1452530285900,\"updated\":1459304874040,\"tz\":480,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004dj5\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004dj5&format=geojson\",\"felt\":1,\"cdi\":2.7,\"mmi\":7.5,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":650,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004dj5\",\"ids\":\",at00o0srjp,pt16011050,us10004dj5,gcmt20160111163807,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":3.144,\"rms\":0.72,\"gap\":22,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.5 - 227km SE of Sarangani, Philippines\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[126.8621,3.8965,13]},\"id\":\"us10004dj5\"},\n" +
                "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6,\"place\":\"Pacific-Antarctic Ridge\",\"time\":1451986454620,\"updated\":1459202978040,\"tz\":-540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004bgk\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004bgk&format=geojson\",\"felt\":0,\"cdi\":1,\"mmi\":0,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":554,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004bgk\",\"ids\":\",us10004bgk,gcmt20160105093415,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":30.75,\"rms\":0.67,\"gap\":71,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.0 - Pacific-Antarctic Ridge\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-136.2603,-54.2906,10]},\"id\":\"us10004bgk\"}],\"bbox\":[-153.4051,-54.2906,10,158.5463,59.6363,582.56]}";

        /**
         * Create a private constructor because no one should ever create a {@link QueryUtils} object.
         * This class is only meant to hold static variables and methods, which can be accessed
         * directly from the class name QueryUtils (and an object instance of QueryUtils is not needed).
         */
        public QueryUtils() {
        }
    /**
     * Return a list of {@link Earthquake} objects that has been built up from
     * parsing a JSON response.
     */
    public static ArrayList<Earthquake> extractEarthquakes() {

        // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding earthquakes to
        ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<Earthquake>();

        // Try to parse the SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
        // is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
        // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.
        try {

            // TODO: Parse the response given by the SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE string and
            // build up a list of Earthquake objects with the corresponding data.

            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE);

            JSONArray featuresArray = root.getJSONArray("features");

            for (int i=0; i<featuresArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject arrayElement = featuresArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject properties = arrayElement.getJSONObject("properties");
                String mag = properties.getString("mag");
                String place = properties.getString("place");
                String time = properties.getString("time");
                earthquakes.add(new Earthquake(mag , place , time));
                Log.v("The Array ------>", earthquakes.get(i).toString());
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
            // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
            // with the message from the exception.
            Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
        }

        // Return the list of earthquakes
        return earthquakes;
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.example.android.quake;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EarthquakeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = EarthquakeActivity.class.getName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.earthquake_activity);

        // Create a fake list of earthquake locations.
        ArrayList<com.example.android.quake.Earthquake> earthquakes = QueryUtils.extractEarthquakes();

        // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
        ListView earthquakeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Create a new {@link ArrayAdapter} of earthquakes
        ArrayAdapter<com.example.android.quake.Earthquake> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<com.example.android.quake.Earthquake>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, earthquakes);

        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface
        earthquakeListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

The ArrayList returns the following Logcat results:

```
04-13 01:01:27.411 16276-16276/? V/The Array ------>: com.example.android.quake.Earthquake@9837b61
04-13 01:01:27.411 16276-16276/? V/The Array ------>: com.example.android.quake.Earthquake@a994686
04-13 01:01:27.411 16276-16276/? V/The Array ------>: com.example.android.quake.Earthquake@8640b47
04-13 01:01:27.411 16276-16276/? V/The Array ------>: com.example.android.quake.Earthquake@df29f74
04-13 01:01:27.411 16276-16276/? V/The Array ------>: com.example.android.quake.Earthquake@49b6c9d
04-13 01:01:27.411 16276-16276/? V/The Array ------>: com.example.android.quake.Earthquake@fb34512
04-13 01:01:27.411 16276-16276/? V/The Array ------>: com.example.android.quake.Earthquake@c4c14e3
04-13 01:01:27.411 16276-16276/? V/The Array ------>: com.example.android.quake.Earthquake@5543ee0
04-13 01:01:27.411 16276-16276/? V/The Array ------>: com.example.android.quake.Earthquake@1473599
04-13 01:01:27.411 16276-16276/? V/The Array ------>: com.example.android.quake.Earthquake@afca05e
```

My question is: Why it returns memory reference : com.example.android.quake.Earthquake@afca05e when it is supposed to return the string value of the object itself? even when I pass the arraylist to an adapter it still pass the memory reference not the object value itself.

Comment: override method toString() in Earthquak class to return the needed data

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've updated your question, my answer still applies.  The toString method is giving a default string representation of the entire object. This includes all the stuff you are seeing.  Did you want the individual pieces?  If so, ((Earthquake)earthquakes.get(i)).mag would be how you access the mag member of the object. You must do this for each member of the object to see only the strings themselves.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the post with my question, thanks for your help